# page request with jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

Can I use jquery to initiate a full page request instead of an asynchronous request?

I'm implementing a countdown timer for a testing app.  I want the timing to persist through page requests, so I'm tracking the time server-side rather than in the browser.  I have a jquery script poll an action every second to check the time and render the time remaining to an html element.  My code:

View:

```
<div id='timer'></div>
```

application.js:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $('#timer').load('/exams/time');
}, 1000);
```

Controller:

```
  def time
    time = check_time
    if time 
      render :text => time
    else
      stop_exam
    end
  end  

  def stop_exam
    @exam = Exam.find(session[:exam])
    @exam.stop
    reset_session
    redirect_to @exam
  end
```

The countdown works fine. However, after the redirect, @exam writes to  rather than the replacing the whole page.  Presumably it is treating the redirect as an AJAX request rather than a full page request.

How can I modify stop_exam to replace the full page (including the javascript so it stops polling?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return a script that when loaded into the div will redirect.  I don't know ruby syntax but return something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   document.location='http://www.google.com';
</script>
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks!  For anyone else who reads this, the rails syntax is render :js => "<script type='text/javascript'> ... </script>"

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into yor view.
Also add one div with id 'count'.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" >
window.onload = function()
{
     startCountdown(<%=cnt=@model.allowed_time%>)
}
</script>
```

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function startCountdown(g_iCount)
{
    if((g_iCount) > 0)
    {
        var str="green";
        if (g_iCount<20&&g_iCount>=10)
        {
            str="orange"
        }
        else if (g_iCount<10)
        {
            str="red"
        }


        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML=g_iCount.toString().fontcolor(str);

        g_iCount = g_iCount - 1;

        setTimeout(function() {

            startCountdown(g_iCount);

        }, 1000);
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('procedure_submit_button').click();
    }
}
</script>
```

Thats all.Your count down will start on page load.